# get a p-value which is greater than 1 in the sign test

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation, hypothesis-testing, p-value

I was confused about calculating the p value for both single sampled sign tests.

Suppose we have a sample size of 12 and 6 values are below our hypothesized median of $m_x$and 6 are above.

And that $H0:m=m_x$ and $H1:m\neq m_x$ with $\alpha=0.05$.

The p value: $2\sum_{i=0}^6\tbinom{12}{i}(\frac{1}{2})^n$, which is obviously geater than 1.

If we run the R code, we get that the p-value is 1.

I know that fact that p-value can never be greater than 1. But  in almost reference books we use the above the formula to calculate the p-value. Can anyone show me the wrong place, thanks in advance.

Comment: You have double counted the value corresponding to $6$ when you multiplied by $2$ (and not counted the value corresponding to $0$) - in effect your two tails overlap

Comment: But according to the formula, we should calculate $2P(K≤6), $where $K\sim B(12,0.5)$

Comment: Yes, I missed $i=0$. Would you mind showing the correct formula when performing the 2-taild test.

Comment: @Henry, would you mind showing me the correct formula to calculate the p-value in the two tailed-test.

Comment: The $p$-value is the probability under the null hypothesis of seeing a result as or more extreme under the null hypothesis.  Since (as a two-tailed test) you have actually observed the least extreme case, you should have  $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{12}\tbinom{12}{i}(\frac{1}{2})^n =1$.  The habit of doubling the one-tailed $p$-value makes a sort of sense for continuous distributions, but is perhaps less reasonable for discrete distributions

Comment: But in many reference books about sign test, the formula for computing the p-value in a two-tailed test is just doubled one-tailed p-value. In the above example, by virtue of R code, we get the outcome that  the one tailed p-value is 0.612. If we doubled 0.612, we get 1.224>1. In sign test, what is the correct formula for calculating p-value?

Comment: Please see this pdf file.  https://www.math.mcgill.ca/~dstephens/OldCourses/204-2007/Handouts/Math204-NonParOneTwo.pdf